# Maven Hibernate with Guice-Persist

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, guice, guice-persist

I'm attempting to use Maven to organize a GWT(GWT-Platform, to be precise) project which uses Guice-persist to map my data objects back to MySQL from Eclipse. I am not having any luck.

I've based my code off of the GWTP basic sample's Maven configuration, which I was able to get working. Now that I'm adding Hibernate dependencies into the `pom.xml` file, I can't seem to get it to run successfully again. Currently, I'm getting the following error:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myappdb
  at com.gwtplatform.samples.basic.server.ApplicationInitializer.<init>(ApplicationInitializer.java:8)
  while locating com.gwtplatform.samples.basic.server.ApplicationInitializer
```

I create my PersistModule when setting up the injector, as such:

```
Injector inject = Guice.createInjector(new ServerModule(),
            new DispatchServletModule(), new JpaPersistModule("myappdb"));
inject.getInstance(ApplicationInitializer.class);
```

My persist file looks like the following:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="myappdb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.gwtplatform.samples.basic.shared.Bird</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://mydbserver.com/mydbname"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="test123" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value ="password123" />

            <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

            <!-- Default is false for backwards compatibility. Should be used on all
                new projects -->
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my `pom.xml` file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtp-samples</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>gwtp-sample-basic</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>GWTP Samples - basic</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                    <style>${gwt.style}</style>
                    <server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                    <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                    <appEngineVersion>${gae.version}</appEngineVersion>
                    <appEngineHome>${gae.home}</appEngineHome>
                    <runTarget>Gwtpsample.html</runTarget>
                    <module>com.gwtplatform.samples.basic.Gwtpsample</module>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
            <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.gaeNature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwtp-build-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Google Web Toolkit dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AppEngine dependencies
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- DI dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
          <artifactId>guice-persist</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-final</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- concrete Log4J Implementation for SLF4J API-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Activate this profile to compile the sample
            including just the adequate GWTP dependencies -->
            <id>default-samples</id>
            <activation>
                <property><name>!gwtp-all</name></property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwtp-mvp-client</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-client</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-server-guice</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- Activate this profile to compile the sample
            using the compound GWTP dependency (gwtp-all) -->
            <id>gwtp-all-samples</id>
            <activation>
                <property><name>gwtp-all</name></property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwtp-all</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

As you can see, then names of the units match. Additionally, I have my `persistance.xml` file saved in the `src/main/webapp/META-INF` directory of the project. I've tried running the project using the `/src/main/webapp/` directory as the base of the war file, as well as the matching directory in `/target/` and neither are able to overcome this error.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! I've been staring at this for 2 days now.

Comment: Have you tried putting your `persistance.xml` file in `src/main/resources/META-INF`?

Comment: Yeah, your persistence.xml is in the wrong place. It should be in `src/main/resources/META-INF` as user463324 indicated.

Comment: @user463324, please make that an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your persistance.xml file in src/main/resources/META-INF.